# How can I rewrite the native HTML input element with Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I want to rewrite the `<input type="number">` element with Polymer so that i can `<input is="number-input">` and style it in a way so that it looks and behaves the same on different browsers.

This is where I'm at now:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="number-input" extends="input" attributes="value">
  <script>
    Polymer('number-input', {
      valueChanged: function(){
        console.log(this.value)
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

... and using it by `<input is="number-input">`, but it doesn't fire the `valueChanged` function.

What am I doin wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teltrik did a recent article on styling inputs with shadow dom that was pretty interesting: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/comprehensive-guide-styling-file-inputs/

In your case, you're doing everything correctly. The problem however, is that `input` already has a `.value` property. You're trying to override the native property which creates unpredictable behavior. The second issues is that `Object.observe()` cannot observe native properties on elements. For example, if you added the `hidden` attribute, `hiddenChanged` would never be called. Likewise for `title` and `titleChanged`.

Comment: Am I correct if I say in this case a better approach would be composition over inheritance, I mean incapsulating the native `<input>` in my own `<number-input>` custom element and exposing one by one the properties I want? Btw the article looks really interesting, I'll give it a go when I got some time to digest it!

Comment: Yep, composition is almost always preferred and easier to deal with.